# Flash php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flash

I'm building a form has part of my exercise. I'm trying to connect Flash to mysql database through PHP to create a login system for Flash. I've setup all the UI componenets and i have finished written my php file.

I am having some URLVariables issues. I copied part of this code from a tutorial and It apeared to work just fine. But when i try to compile it i get 5 errors.

```
Line 33 1120: Access of undefined property status_Txt.
Line 22 1120: Access of undefined property email.
Line 23 1120: Access of undefined property password.
Line 24 1120: Access of undefined property age.
Line 25 1120: Access of undefined property country.
```

Code is below: Can anyone help me please?

```
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import fl.data.DataProvider; 
import fl.events.ComponentEvent;
import fl.controls.TextInput;

//Requesting the php
var phpFileRequest: URLRequest = new URLRequest
phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
//Assing the variable names
//Build the variable
var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

//Building the loader
var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;


//Variables ready for sending
ERRORS phpVars.email = email.text;
phpVars.password = password.text;
phpVars.age = age.text;
phpVars.country = country.text;

phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);

phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);

function showResult (event:Event):void {
ERROR status_Txt.text = "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
trace(event.target.data.systemResult);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't named your UI components. Presumably you have five `TextInput`s on the stage for the user's details. They need to have the *instance names* `status_Txt`, `email`, `password`, `age` and `country`, which your code refers to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. I have other UI components on stage for example combobox, checkbox, button and radio button. They all have the relevant instance names however, the same error keeps popping up. I am just scratching my head wondering what is causing these errors.

Comment: Is the code in your post on the timeline with your UI components, or in a separate .as file? If your components definitely have those names set in their properties, the only other thing I can think of is that they're out of scope.